# Is there a way to trigger an 'basic' action for an dispatched action in ngrx?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx

I'm having the following case:

When one of these actions below gets dispatched i want to set `saving` in the `reducer` to `true`. But at the moment I dont 'catch' these actions in the reducer. I am only 'catch' these in my `effects`. Now i have the question if its possible to create an 'basic' action which gets automatically called when i dispatch my actions below? If it's possible, then i want to catch these 'basic' action in my `reducer` to change the value of `saving`.

```
/**
 * Update Match Conditions
 */
export const updateMatchConditions = createAction(
  AccountMatchingPageConstants.UPDATE_MATCH_CONDITIONS,
  props<{ accountId: string, connection: Connection, matchConditionUpdate: MatchConditionUpdate[] }>()
);

/**
 * Reset Match Conditions
 */
export const resetMatchConditions = createAction(
  AccountMatchingPageConstants.RESET_MATCH_CONDITIONS,
  props<{ accountId: string, connection: Connection }>()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
  loremIpsum$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(updateMatchConditions),
      map(() =>
        basicActions.loremIpsum()
      )
    )
  );
```